# Rewriting this function from product notation

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have a function in product notation and I am wondering if it can be rewritten without using product notation. If so, how could I apply that to similar functions?

$$f(m)=\prod_{n=2}^{m}\frac{2n(2n+1)}{(n+2)(n-1)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(m)=\prod_{n=2}^{m}\frac{2n(2n+1)}{(n+2)(n-1)}=\frac{(2m+1)!/3!}{(m+2)!(m-1)!/3!}$$
$$=\frac{(2m+1)!}{(m+2)!(m-1)!}$$
$$=C^{2m+1}_{m-1}$$